# How do i write partitioned data to a file with the partition value in the filename?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, apache-spark-sql

I unloaded a bunch of data from an RDBMS by month, and loaded it into Google Cloud Storage (GCS) based on that month.  I then read the entire data set into a pyspark data frame on a dataproc cluster, and would like to re-write it to GCS based on the day, rather than the month.  I've successfully written to cloud storage where each file only contains a certain date, but have not been able to **efficiently** name the file or directory based on that date.  The code below does what I want it to do, but it is VERY inefficient.  I also know I could theoretically get around this by rather using parquet files, but my requirements are to write as CSV.  Ultimately I want to load this data into bigquery with a table per day, if there is a solution there that would be easier (and I could then just export each per day table to a file).

```
# Find distinct dates, and then write based on that.
dates = sqlContext.sql("SELECT distinct THE_DATE FROM tbl")

x = dates.collect()

for d in x:
    date = d.SLTRN_DT

    single_wk = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM tbl where THE_DATE = '{}'".format(date))

    towrite = single_wk.map(to_csv)

    towrite.coalesce(4).saveAsTextFile('gs://buck_1/AUDIT/{}'.format(date))
```

So say the data I read in has the dates ['2014-01-01', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03']  I would want the resulting files / directories to look like this:

gs://buck_1/AUDIT/2014-01-01/part-1
gs://buck_1/AUDIT/2014-01-01/part-2
gs://buck_1/AUDIT/2014-01-01/part-3
gs://buck_1/AUDIT/2014-01-01/part-4

gs://buck_1/AUDIT/2014-01-02/part-1
gs://buck_1/AUDIT/2014-01-02/part-2
gs://buck_1/AUDIT/2014-01-02/part-3
gs://buck_1/AUDIT/2014-01-02/part-4

gs://buck_1/AUDIT/2014-01-03/part-1
gs://buck_1/AUDIT/2014-01-03/part-2
gs://buck_1/AUDIT/2014-01-03/part-3
gs://buck_1/AUDIT/2014-01-03/part-4

Comment: Does https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.partitionBy get close to what you need?

Comment: Definitely close.  That allows me to partition the data and ensure that specific files only contain the data for one date (even if in multiple files).  However, it doesn't allow my name my file / directory based on that date.  In other words I would need to read the file to be able to tell what days data is in it, rather than being able to tell by the path.

Comment: Writing a text dataset using df.write.paritionBy('year', 'month') produced a layout like in the following gist: https://gist.github.com/AngusDavis/d22631e72d9358fa7d149513c20e1eb2 which isn't exactly what you're looking for, but might be the simplest way to go.

Comment: To build on that a bit, you could potentially further create a new column in your dataset with formatted date and use that as the paritionBy value.

Comment: Using df.write.partitionBy() without save doesn't actually write the dataset does it?  You still need to use save().  When I did this it was still parittioning by the date, but not including it in the directory:

data.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(path='gs://buck_1/test/AUDIT').partitionBy('THE_DATE').save()

Comment: Sorry thought I added... Using simply df.write.partitionby('THE_DATE').save(<path>) does save as  you mentioned, but it saves in parquet files.  I still need to convert to CSV.

Comment: The complete call would look like this: df.write.paritionBy('THE_DATE').format('text').save(<path>)